# Content cannot scroll - HTML - CSS

Tags: html, css

I've a web view that use dataTable plugin in the content. But the content cannot scrolling when the data when the data is no longer fit displayed on the screen.

[image: The red box is the cannot that cannot be scrolling]

HTML

```
<div class="landing">           
    <div class="wrap mainbar-new">
        <div class="why-container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="center">No</th>
                            <th align="center">Time</th>
                            <th align="center">User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $no=1;
                        foreach($data as $row):?>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><?php echo $no;?></td>
                                <td align="center"><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row->time));?></td>
                                <td align="center"><?php echo $row->user;?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php $no++;
                        endforeach;?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.landing {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 10%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Anybody know what should I do in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: reduce the padding size and also give important to the overflow. better use overflow-x:auto

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: which scroll you want verticle or horizontal?

Comment: please show your datatable configuartion as well..

Comment: I need that padding and I want vertical scroll.